# Intellij not seeing my new JAR

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a Java project that has a dependency on another JAR.  The other JAR recently changed.  When I try running my project in IntelliJ, it throws an error saying a method in the dependency isn't found.

I did a Maven clean, Reimport all Maven Projects, and compile.  All those steps completed successfully, but when trying to run the app, I get the same **method not found** error.

Next, I did a Invalidate Caches/Restart.  I got the same **method not found** error.

I then existed IntelliJ and built and ran my project from the command line.  The app ran perfectly.

Returning to IntelliJ, same **method not found** problem.

What can I do to correct this situation?  TIA

Answer (score 0):

paste that .jar file to libs directory in app then in android studio right click on jar file select 'Add as library' then select 'app' module and click ok. Then app will rebuilt and jar will be added.
To verify jar is added or not, check whether there is arrow before .jar file name in AS, if there .jar is added successfully